# MySql ENCLOSED BY double quote

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

What's wrong with this code in a php file?

```
$q = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '$file'  INTO TABLE $table  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES" ;
echo "LOAD DATA query = " . $q . "<br />";
mysqli_query($DBlink, $q) or die (mysqli_error($DBlink));
```

It looks like many examples I've seen, but I get the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /users13/domains/efsowell.us/web/ed/JOCMemDB/CSV_MySQL.php on line 66

Answer (score 3):

You can see from the syntax highlighting that you have an issue.

```
$q = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '$file'  
INTO TABLE $table  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '\"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES" ;
echo "LOAD DATA query = " . $q . "<br />";
mysqli_query($DBlink, $q) or die (mysqli_error($DBlink));
```

You need to escape quotes within strings. If your string is double quoted, you must escape double-quotes. If it's single quoted, same goes for single quotes.

You can also take advantage of variable interpolation with double quotes.

```
$q = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '{$file}'  
INTO TABLE $table  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '\"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES" ;
echo "LOAD DATA query = {$q}<br />"; //<-- This line.
mysqli_query($DBlink, $q) or die (mysqli_error($DBlink));
```

Comment: Thanks Jessica! I thought I had tried the escaping but perhaps I was thinking special chars were escaped with doubles. Anyway, '\"' works!